# How can I know how many messages are waiting for Actor to process

Tags: kotlin, actor, kotlinx.coroutines

I am using actor from Kotlin coroutines like this:

```
actor<Action>(CommonPool, 0, parent = job) {
        consumeEach { action ->
            when (action) {
                is Spin -> spin(action.id)
                is Done -> action.ack.complete(true)
            }
        }
    }
```

For debugging purposes, I would like to know how many messages are waiting on the channel for processing. How is it possible?

Comment: channel.toString() provides a bit of debugging info

Comment: @RomanElizarov this is what I see in toString: `"coroutine#2":ActorCoroutine{Active}@69eed470` what can I understand from that?

Comment: You are right. Not much at the moment. I've recorded your ask here https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/730